# Python Array Computations: get two values per item

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I'm trying to get a list with all numbers that are in the form 6n+1 or 6n-1.
Currently I have this:

```
n = 100000000
l = int(n/6)
f1 = lambda x: (6*x)-1
f3 = lambda x: (6*x)+1
primeCandidate = [f(i) for i in range(1,l+1) for f in (f1,f3)]
```

This works nicely, and it gets me 2 values on the list per i, but I was wondering if I could do something similar with NumPy arrays

Comment: Why don't you use just `range` with defining the step?

Comment: @AmirhosseinKiani you mean changing `range(1,l+1)` to `range(1,n,6)`?

Comment: Kinda, you probably need to generate two ranges and eliminate the first element of each. range is not comparable to the numpy answers. I suggest you to use them, and do not consider range at all:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this. When you divide a number by 6, the modulo has to be either 1 or 5:

```
arr = np.arange(2, n)
out = arr[np.isin(np.mod(arr, 6), [1,5])]
```

Test:

```
assert arr[np.isin(np.mod(arr, 6), [1,5])].tolist() == [f(i) for i in range(1,l+1) for f in (f1,f3)]
```

Answer (score 3):

Certainly.

```
pc1 = np.arange(0,n,6)+5
pc2 = np.arange(0,n,6)+1
pc = np.concatenate((pc1,pc2))
```

Comment: Thanks! But, would there be a way to make this in order without recurring to sorting?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `np.dstack` with two `np.arange()`s and a `.reshape(-1)`:

```
primeCandidates = np.dstack((np.arange(5,n,6), np.arange(7,n,6))).reshape(-1)
```

Test:

```
>>> np.all(np.dstack((np.arange(5,n,6), np.arange(7,n,6))).reshape(-1) == [f(i) for i in range(1,l+1) for f in (f1,f3)])
True
```

This seems to beat enke's in terms of performance by about 10 times:

```
%timeit enke()
3.22 s ± 116 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit richardec()
259 ms ± 57.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Credit goes to [Michael Szczesny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14277722/michael-szczesny) for suggesting to use `reshape(-1)` instead of `ravel` for speed, and for cleaning up the starts, stops, and steps of the ranges!